# Set how many files winston daily logrotate should keep

Tags: node.js, logging, winston, log-rotation

I'm implementing logging for a node app and need some advice: I've read some stuff about `winston.transports.DailyRotateFile` but I still don't get, where can I configure, how much daily log files should it keep. Where can I set it? Also, where do I configure it to compress old logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the following two options:

- zippedArchive
- maxFiles

Example:

```
new (winston.transports.DailyRotateFile)({
  level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL || 'error',
  name: 'log.all',
  colorize: false,
  timestamp: true,
  json: false,
  filename: `logs/famitsu-server`,
  datePattern: '.yyyy-MM-dd.log',
  zippedArchive: true,
  maxFiles: 10,
}),
```